# drawable-mdpi folder for handsets and tablets

Tags: android, tablet, android-screen-support, mdpi, handset

I am developing an Android application for handsets and tablets. I have images in drawable-mdpi folder for handsets, I have an mdpi tablet that gets resources from drawable-mdpi. How can I make difference between mdpi handsets and mdpi tablets?

Comment: duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android follow this link

Answer (score 0):

simply do it with dimen

for Handset use default values dimens.xml

values-sw600dp for 7 inch Tablate add dimens.xml

values-sw720dp 10 inch Tablate add dimens.xml

also create drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp

Answer (score 0):

You will find solution in these two links.

1. For understanding drawable folder properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753138/3110234)
2. For differentiating tablets and devices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113877/3110234)

Hope this helps.