# Which .png file do I have to replace for changing Icon symbol in Android Studios

Tags: android, icons

When you code on Android Studio there is a standard icon symbol ( green Android ). I know how to change it. When I go to manifests.xml and look at this line

```
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

the icon launcher must be in the directory "mipmap". When I go to mipmap, there are several .png files of ic_launcher.
Such as

```
ic_launcher.png(hdpi)
ic_launcher.png(mdpi)
ic_launcher.png(xhdpi)
ic_launcher.png(xxhdpi) 
ic_launcher.png(xxxhdpi)
```

The question now is which of these files do I have to replace in order to get a new custom icon? Thank you.

Comment: all of them but obviously they should have different sizes

Comment: Ah, I see. What is the sense of having several files? Is it because of the quality ? When it's because of the sizes: Which png file is being used when I install my app on my smartphone? Does is automatically recognize which file to use ?

Comment: It would be better to do some internet search ... search about mipmaps on android ...

Comment: OK, I will, thank you very much.

Comment: here is the clean explanation of what you are looking for ,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752997/how-mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi-folder-works

Comment: Ah, I was looking for such a good explanation. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Image Asset wizard. This allows you to add an Image Launcher which is the kind of image for your App's logo

[Image Asset Pop-up Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNxGq.png)

Image Asset will ensure all resolutions and sizes for the logo.

Answer (score 1):

They are categorized according to the size of screen for example tablet users uses xxhdi ic_launcher.png and hdpi ic_launcher.png for small size screen like 3 inches screen. If you are  developing cool apps then you need to resize your icons for  all these mentions size otherwise you can make any size and call  them in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

All of them because each one of them means that the icon will be displayed on the device depending on the size of the screen that is "from the smallest to the largest".

A tip if you are going to use the same icon for each one, first create the bigger image and then reduce it, I think the same android studio is reduced when you use the option because of the icon I think you can call application icon.

The biggest image is 512, this is the image of the web that will be displayed in the Play Store